# Environment variable %USERPROFILE% doesn't work on windows

Tags: windows, environment-variables

It's a very weird problem, my environment variable doesn't work well.

In the setting interface, I set these 3 env vars like this:

```
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\10031
TEMP=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

`10031` is my username.

And when I save it, it shows this:

```
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\10031
TEMP=C:\Users\10031\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\10031\AppData\Local\Temp
```

However, when I access the variable, it shows like:

```
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\10031
TEMP=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\10031\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Why is `TEMP` different from `TMP` here? It causes some problems on my computer. All of these variables are set in the local.

Comment: What **setting interface**? And what specifically does **when I access the variable** mean?

Comment: did you.. define `USERPROFILE`, `TEMP`, and `TMP`  by yourself? i thought that values are a reserved? also, how did you access both `TEMP` and `TMP`? both of them should be interchangeable.

Comment: Have you changed your user directory by chance?  I've done that before and it was an utter nightmare to try to fix afterwards... not recommended.

Comment: @KenWhite The windows "env variables" interface. And I use "set" the command or "echo %XXX%" to access the variable, it returns like what iv mentioned above.

Comment: @BagusTesa No, I havent change it... for some reason, I cannot upload image. I use command like "set" or "echo %XXX%" to access them.

Comment: @Brad Thank you for the reminder, but not. I havent change it since I used the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Acturally I found a way to solve the problem.

Just turn the wrong env variables into **absolute path**, like:

```
TEMP=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp -> TEMP=C:\Users\10031\AppData\Local\Temp
```

save, and restart your windows.

then change it back:

```
TEMP=C:\Users\10031\AppData\Local\Temp -> TEMP=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

this can fix your problem.

Comment: thats odd, i do wonder what happen under the hood. which version of windows you had this issue with?

Comment: @BagusTesa I'm on 22631.2361 in_release.